# New serial number for records using row number

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have a table with columns 'id' and 'name'

```
id Name
1  John
2  Peter
3  Alex
4  Robin
5  Mario
```

so when I delete a record '3 Alex' It should look like below. I know it's possible using Row number, but I don't know how to do it. I need a proper sql for this one to use in vb.net (or access).

```
id Name
1  John
2  Peter
3  Robin
4  Mario
```

Comment: Why does this matter to you? It is not a good idea.

Comment: ***DON'T*** do this. The id of an entity should never change due to actions made on another entity. It will break Foreign Key relationships, amoung other problems. If this is for sorting, counting, etc, add new fields for those purposes, then manipulate those however is necessary. *[The `id` should be a static identifier, and other fields can be transitive data associated with that `id`.]*  Can you imagine being given a new bank account number, phone number, etc, every time another customer leaves???

Comment: @Dems Can't agree with this enough. +1 for that comment isn't enough.

Comment: Agreeing with all the above. 1,2,4,5 are still *ordered*

Comment: And if you actually meant to use the column strictly for sorting, maybe you shouldn't call it `id` then, that's really misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a temp table:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(
[Name] VARCHAR(64) NULL
, OldID INT NULL
, NewID INT INCREMENT(1,1)
) 

INSERT INTO @tbl
 (
 [Name]
 , OldID
 )
 SELECT
 [Name]
 , ID
 FROM
   OriginalDataTable
 WHERE
    ID  NOT IN (4, 5) ' actually 3 for your example
 ORDER BY
   ID

SELECT
 [Name]
 , NewID ID
FROM
  @tbl
ORDER BY 
 NewID
```

I'm sort of assuming that you really dont want to change the actual ID as this as mentioned above is not good practice.